# Search String in an arrayed text file

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search

I took a text file and put it in one array. However, I want to search for a String (word) within the array. In my case I wanted to use the scanner to get input from the user, then search for a string match in the array. How can one achieve such a task?

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
    //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String stringSearch = scan.nextLine();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File1.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    words.add(line);        
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(words);
}
```

My output:

```
[CHAPTER I. Down the Rabbit-Hole, Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the, bank, and of having nothing to do:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .contains() function from List. It will use the .equals() method of the parameter on each element

```
words.contains("your_string")
```

Just realized you are saving one line per index, and not one word. In this case:

```
for(String sLine : words) {
    if (sLine.contains("your_string")) {
         System.out.println("Got a match");
         break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
  if(words.get(i).equals(string)){
     found!!
  }
}
```

Comment: He's adding the total lines without splitting. Use String.contains instead

Answer (score 0):

The `equals()` method suggested by others will only work if you have one word per line. Try iterating over the list and see if one (or more) of the strings [contains(word)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) the word you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something with the scanner like this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("File1.txt"));
String targetString = "whatYouWant";
String testString = sc.next();
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    if(testString.equals(targetString))
        hooray!
}
```

This isn't a full solution but hopefully this will guide you to a working solution.